# If $V_1, V_2$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces and $f \colon V_1 \to V_2$ is additive, then $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces over the field of rational numbers and $f \colon V_1 \to V_2$ is a map such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y \in V_1$, show that $f$ is a linear transformation.

It is easy to show that $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-x$.
Here scalars are from rationals. If scalar is an integer then clearly $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$. Hence $f$ is a linear transformation.

Now I have to show that when $\alpha$ is not an integer then $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inductively, you can show that $\;f(nx)=nf(x)\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and then for $\;0\neq n\in\Bbb Z\;$ :

$$f(x)=f\left(n\cdot\frac xn\right)=nf\left(\frac1nx\right)\implies f\left(\frac1nx\right)=\frac1nf(x)$$

and from here

$$f\left(\frac mnx\right)=mf\left(\frac1nx\right)=\frac mnf(x)$$